# Validator for drop down list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, validation

I have a drop down list which I am loading from the server side.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOne" runat="server"  CssClass="dropDrownClass" Width="80%">
```

In server side, after loading the drop down I am adding

> -- Please Select --

I want to make sure that if that is selected than I would display the error message. For that I have written

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                          ControlToValidate="ddlOne" ValueToCompare="-- Please Select --" Operator="Equal"  Type="String"   ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" TargetControlID="CompareValidator1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

But it is showing me the error message whenever I am selecting anything in the drop down list. 
and when I changed the validator to

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                          ControlToValidate="ddlOne" ValueToCompare="0" Operator="Equal"  Type="Integer"  ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

I am getting the error message on every selection, except the first which is -- Please Select -- .

Please let me know how to validate the fist item of dropdown list

**ISSUE 2**

I am getting dual message, one under the dropdown list [which is showing error "Carson63000" in red] and one as a pop up [validator call out]. Same message.
I want that only validator callout should display the message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your validator will compare the *value* of the dropdown's selected item, not the *text*. The easiest way is often to have an empty string for the value of the "Please Select" item, have a non-empty value for the other items, and then just use a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Additionally, a `CompareValidator` with `ValueToCompare="-- Please Select --"` and `Operator="Equal"` means: check the value of the dropdown, and validate that it is equal to "-- Please Select --"; if not, display the error. Which is the exact opposite of what you need - you'd want to change the operator to `Operator="NotEqual"` if you wanted to take the approach of using a `CompareValidator`.

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks. But I am getting dual message. One from the callout extender and one under the dropdownlist. I want to display message only once.

Comment: @Chris, I'm afraid I've never used a ValidatorCalloutExtender. That's an ASP.NET AJAX thing, right? Have you tried adding `Display="None"` to the CompareValidator?

Comment: notice that if the value to compare was an empty string you would have to use a required field validator (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Did not know putting an empty value in the value attribute would trigger the RequiredFieldValidator. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the **Operator** value:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlOne" ValueToCompare="0" Operator="NotEqual"
     Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 basic things that need to be understood when working with DropDownList items.
*(The use of the word "compare" below is any logical comparison, not Validator specific.)*

**There are three things you will typically compare against in the DropDownList.**

1. Selected Index - This is a 0 based index you can reference in code.
2. Selected Value - This is an integer and doesn't have to begin with 0 or be in any particular order. You will often see this value representing a database ID.
3. Selected Item - This is normally the visible text of the row in the list.

Using `ValueToCompare' in a Validator is tricky because you are comparing the Selected Value, which is not the same thing as the Index, but sometimes *has* the same values. 
Which you will see depends on how you are creating your data list for the dropdown.

- If you use a List type and bind it to the DropDown, you could set the DropDown's Value to the index's index value.
- If you got the list from a DB query, you might set the Value to the database ID of each item.
- If you take an empty DropDown and populate it via **DropDownList.Items.Add** you could get a different result than from:
- If you took an existing list and added items via **DropDownList.Items.Insert** a variety of things could happen.

For example, look at the following code:

```
protected void DetailsView_New_Form_DataBound (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList webform_type = (DropDownList)DetailsView_New_Form.FindControl("DropDownList_DV_New_webform_type");
            webform_type.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
```

Even though I am inserting the "--Select--"at index 0 of the dropdown, I am setting it's value to a string value of "0", not an int value of 0. It doesn't actually insert at index 0, however, it is inserted at -1. The only way the compare works in my scenario is if the ValueToCompare = "-1".  That *would* be 0 if the first thing added to the dropdown was the "Select".  Sine I am adding it to an already bound dropdown the 0 becomes -1. Therefore this Validator works:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="webform_type_Validator" CssClass="validator"
ErrorMessage=" *Required!" ControlToValidate="DropDownList_DV_New_webform_type"
InitialValue="0" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" 
ValidationGroup="InsertForm" />
```